# Conformability error when using estfe with extended absvars

Tags: stata

I run a simple regression with `reghdfe` and would like to manually add three indicators to that.

Let's first try with one indicator

```
sysuse auto.dta
eststo m0: quietly reghdfe price turn, a(foreign)
estadd local extended_absvars = " a", replace
ereturn list
estfe m1, labels(a "A" b "B" c "C")
```

that worked like a charm. Now, with three:

```
eststo m1: quietly reghdfe price turn, a(foreign)
estadd local extended_absvars = " a b c", replace
ereturn list
estfe m1, labels(a "A" b "B" c "C")
>> conformability error
r(503);
```

The last lines from the stack trace are:

```
---------------------------------------- end estfe.FixAbsvars ----
- if ("`absvars'"=="" & "`e(model'"=="fe") local absvars "`e(ivar)'"
= if ("0.a 0.b 0.c"=="" & ""=="fe") local absvars ""
- matrix `new' = J(1, `G', 0)
= matrix __000002 = J(1 , 1, 0)
- matrix colnames `new' = `absvars'
= matrix colnames __000002 = 0.a 0.b 0.c
conformability error
---------------------------------------- end estfe.AddOne ----
local fe_list `fe_list' `absvars'
}
---------------------------------------- end estfe.Add ----
---------------------------------------- end estfe ----
```

Why is this happening? Certainly if this was a common error I would have seen more about it when searching the web for the issue, but it appears unique? My version of `reghdfe` is `5.9.0` and `ftools` are installed.

Comment: @NickCox That's because I'm manually typing up from a remote desktop session where I cannot copy&paste from. I've added the stack trace.

Comment: OK. As you can see the code is trying to assign three column names to a matrix with one column. If you don't get a good answer here, I'd email the program author, who I don't think it's active here. Or there may be a GitHub way to raise a question.